# Generate absolute URL to a route from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm currently working on a react application, that needs to be easily deployed to multiple locations (white label) and with no initial configuration.

The application, regardless of location, uses the same single API endpoint, which handles sending of emails, that also includes links back to the application.

An example of this, would be the user password recovery process, which would send the users email address and a link to the password reset route for that particular instance of the application, i.e. 'http://a.nother.instance/auth/reset/%s'

I can use `window.location.origin` but it's not widely supported and it would be useful if you could generate an url, similarly to the way you use `<Link to={'/auth/reset/' + token}>Reset</a>`

Is there any other way?

**Update**

I wanted an out of the box solution, however for now this is the best I can find:

```
export function generateUrl(path: any) {
    return `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}${path}`
}
```